# CKeditor multiple instances: cannot get any other instance except for the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, ckeditor, wysiwyg

My page has ***two*** CKeditor instances with completely ***different id and name*** attributes.
CKeditor is successfully visualized and getting the first instance's value by

```
CKEDITOR.instances['add-message-content'].getData();
```

is no problem at all.
Doing the same thing on the other intance however is a whole new experience.

```
CKEDITOR.instances['edit-message-content'].getData();
```

throws

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined

Here is my code behind.

```
function editComment(commentId) {

if (document.getElementById('edit-comment-div') !== null) {
    return;
}

var newTextEditor = $('<div class="form-group" id="edit-comment-div">' +
    '<label class="control-label">Message:</label>' +
    '<textarea id="edit-message-content" name="edit-message-content"></textarea>' +
    '</div>');

var newTextArea = newTextEditor.find('textarea');

//attaches CK editor to the new textarea successfully
addCkEditor(newTextArea.attr('id'));

$(".comments-container").prepend(newTextEditor);
sendEditAjax(commentId);
}

function sendEditAjax(commentId) {
    var dataToSend = {
        'id': commentId,
        'Message': CKEDITOR.instances['edit-message-content'].getData() //throws the error here
    };
```

I'm very baffled because `console.dir(CKEDITOR.instances)` returns an object with both instances in it and everything seems fine until on the next line i try to get the second one's value.
I attach a photo of my page and the JavaScript console next to it.

[[image: Here it is. Click!]<sup>Click for larger</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkzP1.png)

The second textarea is added dynamically using jQuery. I dont think it could be some asynchronous problem because it gets both instances before any getData() call. Anyone?

***P.S Note that if i write `CKEDITOR.instances['edit-message-content'].getData();` later in the browser's JavaScript console it return the data successfully.***

Comment: What happens if you add the second one normally rather than with jQuery? Can you at least confirm that that might be the issue?

Comment: @MattFletcher same happens. Even if add the textarea manually to the html, it just wont get the data. Throws the same error as well because the second instance is undefined

Comment: Shouldn't you prepend element to the DOM **before** initialize ckeditor on it?

Comment: I don't know this plugin but i guess `addCkEditor()` is one custom function that initialize CKEditor using some async method, maybe an ajax call. If so, then the behaviour you are facing is normal because the console shows the updated version of object. You should be at least able to test it using instead: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(CKEDITOR.instances)));`

Comment: @A.Wolff Here are the related functions

`function addCkEditor(textareaId, formId) {
    //attaches the editor to the text area
    CKEDITOR.replace(textareaId);

    updateEditorElements();
    if (formId === "") {
        return;
    }

    $("#" + formId).on("submit", updateEditorElements);
}

function updateEditorElements() {
    var instance;
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        if (CKEDITOR.instances.hasOwnProperty(instance)) {
            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement(() => all);
        }
    }
}`